# Discrete Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

If n is a positive integer, the integers a and b are congruent modulo n, i.e.
a ≡ b (mod n), if they have the same remainder after division by n.
Prove that a ≡ b (mod n) if and only if n|(a − b).

Comment: It's better to think of $a\cong b\pmod n$ as being defined by $n\mid(a-b)$ rather than anything involving remainders.

Comment: But the exercise posed is to show that the two definitions are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

But the exercise posed is to show that the two definitions are equivalent so the fact that one is "better" is irrelevant.

Suppose that a and b have the same remainders when divided by n.  Call that common remainder "z".  Then a= pn+ z for some integer p and b= qn+ z for some integer q.  a- b= pn- qn= (p- q)n since "z" terms cancel so a- b= 0 (mod n).

Conversely, if a- b= 0 (mod n) then a- b= rn for some integer n.   Suppose b has remainder z when divided by n.  That is, b= pn+ z for some integer p.  From a- b= rn, a= b+ rn= pn+ z+ rn= (p+r)n+ z. So a also has remainder z when divided by n.